# Type based collection partitioning in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections, shapeless

Given the following data model:

```
sealed trait Fruit

case class Apple(id: Int, sweetness: Int) extends Fruit

case class Pear(id: Int, color: String) extends Fruit
```

I've been looking to implement a segregate basket function which for the given basket of fruits will return separate baskets of apples and pears:

`def segregateBasket(fruitBasket: Set[Fruit]): (Set[Apple], Set[Pear])`

I've attempted a couple of approaches, but none of them seems to be fitting the bill perfectly. Below are my attempts:

```
  def segregateBasket1(fruitBasket: Set[Fruit]): (Set[Apple], Set[Pear]) = fruitBasket
    .partition(_.isInstanceOf[Apple])
    .asInstanceOf[(Set[Apple], Set[Pear])]
```

This is the most concise solution I've found, but suffers from explicit type casting via `asInstanceOf` and is going to be a pain to extend should I decide to add additional types of fruits. Therefore:

```
  def segregateBasket2(fruitBasket: Set[Fruit]): (Set[Apple], Set[Pear]) = {
    val mappedFruits = fruitBasket.groupBy(_.getClass)
    val appleSet = mappedFruits.getOrElse(classOf[Apple], Set()).asInstanceOf[Set[Apple]]
    val pearSet = mappedFruits.getOrElse(classOf[Pear], Set()).asInstanceOf[Set[Pear]]
    (appleSet, pearSet)
  }
```

Resolves the problem of additional fruit types (extension really easy), but still strongly depends on risky type casting 'asInstanceOf' which I'd rather avoid.  Therefore:

```
  def segregateBasket3(fruitBasket: Set[Fruit]): (Set[Apple], Set[Pear]) = {
    val appleSet = collection.mutable.Set[Apple]()
    val pearSet = collection.mutable.Set[Pear]()

    fruitBasket.foreach {
      case a: Apple => appleSet += a
      case p: Pear => pearSet += p
    }
    (appleSet.toSet, pearSet.toSet)
  }
```

Resolves the problem of explicit casting, but uses mutable collections and ideally I'd like to stick with immutable collections and idiomatic code.

I've looked here: [Scala: Filtering based on type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572195/scala-filtering-based-on-type) for some inspiration, but couldn't find a better approach either.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how this functionality can be better implemented in Scala?

Comment: It sounds like the "real" question *might* be about an n-way partition [pattern].. (whereas types are mostly secondary aside from their use as a discriminator; none of the real uglies with [sub]types have been touched upon)

Comment: i.e. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259790/single-iteration-multiple-output-collections-from-java-to-scala (in this case the partition might be on the Class; but with a generic n-way partition the static typing is lost in Scala, without a separate strongly-typed lookup/association)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
  val emptyBaskets: (List[Apple], List[Pear]) = (Nil, Nil)

  def separate(fruits: List[Fruit]): (List[Apple], List[Pear]) = {
    fruits.foldRight(emptyBaskets) { case (f, (as, ps)) =>
      f match {
        case a @ Apple(_, _) => (a :: as, ps)
        case p @ Pear(_, _)  => (as, p :: ps)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: That's a great solution to the problem, slightly more complex than Rex's but with only a single run though the basket it's great. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: the extra match can be removed: 
`fruits.foldRight(emptyBaskets) {     
    case (a @ Apple(_, _), (as, ps)) => (a :: as, ps) 
    case (p @ Pear(_, _), (as, ps)) => (as, p :: ps)  
}`

Answer (score 15):

An "immutable" solution would use your mutable solution except not show you the collections.  I'm not sure there's a strong reason to think it's okay if library designers do it but anathema for you.  However, if you want to stick to purely immutable constructs, this is probably about as good as it gets:

```
def segregate4(basket: Set[Fruit]) = {
  val apples = basket.collect{ case a: Apple => a }
  val pears = basket.collect{ case p: Pear => p }
  (apples, pears)
}
```

Comment: That's my favorite solution in terms of readability and will work like a charm for small collections (where iteration through collection multiple times doesn't add a large overhead). Thank you very much Rex.

Comment: How nice :- )  This reduced a [could have been 5 lines incl a mutable `var` or an `ArrayBuffer`] to just an easy to read one liner

Answer (score 10):

It's possible to do this in a very clean and generic way using Shapeless 2.0's `LabelledGeneric` type class. First we define a type class that will show how to partition a list with elements of some algebraic data type into an `HList` of collections for each constructor:

```
import shapeless._, record._

trait Partitioner[C <: Coproduct] extends DepFn1[List[C]] { type Out <: HList }
```

And then for the instances:

```
object Partitioner {
  type Aux[C <: Coproduct, Out0 <: HList] = Partitioner[C] { type Out = Out0 }

  implicit def cnilPartitioner: Aux[CNil, HNil] = new Partitioner[CNil] {
    type Out = HNil

    def apply(c: List[CNil]): Out = HNil
  }

  implicit def cpPartitioner[K, H, T <: Coproduct, OutT <: HList](implicit
    cp: Aux[T, OutT]
  ): Aux[FieldType[K, H] :+: T, FieldType[K, List[H]] :: OutT] =
    new Partitioner[FieldType[K, H] :+: T] {
      type Out = FieldType[K, List[H]] :: OutT

      def apply(c: List[FieldType[K, H] :+: T]): Out =
        field[K](c.collect { case Inl(h) => (h: H) }) ::
        cp(c.collect { case Inr(t) => t })
  }
}
```

And then the `partition` method itself:

```
implicit def partition[A, C <: Coproduct, Out <: HList](as: List[A])(implicit
  gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, C],
  partitioner: Partitioner.Aux[C, Out]
) = partitioner(as.map(gen.to))
```

Now we can write the following:

```
val fruits: List[Fruit] = List(
  Apple(1, 10),
  Pear(2, "red"),
  Pear(3, "green"),
  Apple(4, 6),
  Pear(5, "purple")
)
```

And then:

```
scala> val baskets = partition(fruits)
partitioned: shapeless.:: ...

scala> baskets('Apple)
res0: List[Apple] = List(Apple(1,10), Apple(4,6))

scala> baskets('Pear)
res1: List[Pear] = List(Pear(2,red), Pear(3,green), Pear(5,purple))
```

We could also write a version that would return a tuple of the lists instead of using the `record('symbol)` syntax—see [my blog post here](http://meta.plasm.us/posts/2014/06/14/partitioning-by-constructor/) for details.

Comment: What is this sorcery! I want to understand this so bad (I'm writing Scala for a living for a few years and know Scala pretty well, but this type sorcery with Scalaz / Shapeless / Algebraic types / Macros and those `:+:` (union type?) has always both baffled me and intrigued me. I keep saying to myself that this is a distraction, that I don't need it for my day to day job (and I don't most of the time) but my ego doesn't let me rest until I understand all of it. (and I can understand `CanBuildFrom` and type classes! you would think I would give it a rest) where do I learn this inside out?

Answer (score 9):

Starting in `Scala 2.13`, `Set`s (and most collections) are provided with a [`partitionMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/Set.html#partitionMap%5BA1,A2%5D(f:A=%3EEither%5BA1,A2%5D):(CC%5BA1%5D,CC%5BA2%5D)) method which partitions elements based on a function which returns either `Right` or `Left`.

By pattern matching on the type we can map `Pear`s into `Left[Pear]` and `Apple`s into `Right[Apple]` for `partitionMap` to create a tuple of pears and apples:

```
val (pears, apples) =
  Set(Apple(1, 10), Pear(2, "red"), Apple(4, 6)).partitionMap {
    case pear: Pear   => Left(pear)
    case apple: Apple => Right(apple)
}
// pears: Set[Pear] = Set(Pear(2, "red"))
// apples: Set[Apple] = Set(Apple(1, 10), Apple(4, 6))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little confused by your examples.  The return type of each of your "segregate" methods is a `Tuple2`, yet you want to be able to add more types of `Fruit` freely.  Your method will need to return something with dynamic length (`Iterable`/`Seq`/etc) since the length of a tuple needs to be deterministic at compile time.

With that said, maybe I'm oversimplifying it but what about just using `groupBy`?

```
val fruit = Set(Apple(1, 1), Pear(1, "Green"), Apple(2, 2), Pear(2, "Yellow"))
val grouped = fruit.groupBy(_.getClass)
```

And then do whatever you want with the keys/values:

```
grouped.keys.map(_.getSimpleName).mkString(", ") //Apple, Pear
grouped.values.map(_.size).mkString(", ") //2, 2
```

**link: http://ideone.com/M4N0Pd**